# Control API requests are not executed outside application

Tags: api, http, python-requests

Is there a way to stop a user to clone a request and executed manually?
let's say a user copies the headers, and payload from the network browser (inspect console) and executes the request in postman/insomnia/etc.

I was thinking of using some kind of token that the server validates only to be used once, therefore the user who is trying to executed manually gets an error (token was already used) but perhaps there is an already existing solution for this use case.

Thanks in advance.